# Neo4j automatic index doesn't work first time

Tags: lucene, neo4j, full-text-search, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have a following test:

```
  @Test
    public void testAutoIndexingAndFuzzySearch() {
        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = template.getGraphDatabaseService();

        Index<Node> autoIndex = graphDb.index().forNodes("node_auto_index");
        graphDb.index().setConfiguration(autoIndex, "type", "fulltext");
        graphDb.index().setConfiguration(autoIndex, "to_lower_case", "true");
        graphDb.index().setConfiguration(autoIndex, "analyzer", StandardAnalyzerV36.class.getName());

        sampleDataGenerator.generateSampleDataJava();

        List<Product> products = // query - "name:aDbma~";

        Assert.assertFalse(products.isEmpty());
    }
```

Every first time on the fresh embedded database the test fails. Auto index doesn't work. Test starts to work only each second time. First time products are empty..

What could be a reason of this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in the configuration to the *very* first call to `forNodes(index,config)`